# Routing requirements 0

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony-2.2

I have a problem with my Symfony2.2 beta routes. (symfony-2-2-0-beta-1)

I use annoations routes like this:

```
@Route("/form/{id}", defaults={"id"=0}, requirements={"id"="\d+"});
```

And the error is:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "id" for route "[...]_form" must match "\d+" ("" given).") in [...]:form.html.twig at line 1.

The line 1 is:

```
{{ path("[...]_form") }}
```

I think the route is correct, because I define "id=0" as default.
And in Symfony2.1 the same code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the default in your action and taking it out of the annotation?

```
/**
 * @Route("/form/{id}", name="my_form", requirements={"id"="\d+"});
 */
public function myFunction($id = 0){
...
```

I believe this is one of the changes in Symfony 2.2 although I haven't tried it yet. http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-2-small-things-matter#defining-default-values-when-using-the-route-annotation

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
    requirements:
    id: \S|\d+
```

Comment: This is YAML while the question is about PHP annotation, and there is already a valid answer.